# JS Constantly updating CSS background colors in a grid - closure?

Tags: javascript, css, closures

I have a grid of boxes (3x2) that I'd like to update in a loop given a large array of rgb values representing changing colors over time. An example of one element of the array looks like this:

[[99.58221354166666, 99.20004050925925, 100.86330150462963], [59.431727430555554, 58.59181712962963, 61.26002314814815], [59.824817708333335, 58.83816550925926, 61.85647280092593], [93.02857349537037, 95.04584201388889, 92.13913194444444], [48.46075810185185, 50.74021701388889, 46.878373842592595], [84.57517939814815, 173.51900462962962, 62.35618923611111]]

The code below handles the rgb values and everything perfectly. Each element of the array corresponds to a "box" in the 3x2 grid. Unfortunately, my loop seems to have a closure problem and I can't figure it out. It only updates the grid's colors on the last iteration. So I rewrote it to store a list of functions and then call those, but I can't tell if it's just executing so fast I can't see it or if it's actually failing. If I add a sleep in, the script will hang and wherever it hangs it'll update for that one moment until I click continue script. After which it'll show me the last update (so I've gone from seeing on the last update to seeing two with a script apparently hanging).

```
c1 = $("#cell1");
c2 = $("#cell2");
c3 = $("#cell3");
c4 = $("#cell4");
c5 = $("#cell5");
c6 = $("#cell6");
var cells = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(test, function(iGrid, grid) {
        var ary_rgb = [];
        var property = "background";
        var updates = [];
        $.each(grid, function (iBox, box) {
            var r = Math.floor(box[0]).toString();
            var g = Math.floor(box[1]).toString();
            var b = Math.floor(box[2]).toString();
            var rgb = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
            updates[iBox] = function () { return cells[iBox].css(property, rgb); };
        });

        for (var i=0; i<updates.length;i++) {
            updates[i]();
        }
    });
});
```

I did spend several hours trying to get this working and reading SO and other sites on closures but I just can't see what I'm doing wrong. I can post the rest of the html if needed.

Comment: I'm not seeing any closure issues here. It's hard to tell though, because this is an incomplete snippet. Also what's `test`? (it's impossible to tell here). Also, the assignments of `c1` thru `c6` should happen within the `$(document).ready()` handler. You'll get better feedback if you could produce a runnable jsFiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/rBLLc/2/

This has the commented out and the way i was originally trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you're going for, no? http://jsfiddle.net/rBLLc/4/

Basically, like you suggested, all your updates were happening rapidly, one after the other and the browser never has a chance to render the changes.

(There was also a javascript error in the jsfiddle, due to `updates` being undefined).

You need to space apart the updates, using `setTimeout` as shown in the link.

Comment: Thank you so much. I get it now, the inner loop needs to be inside the setTimeout. I'm tracking live the dominant values for sections on a display. This is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I'm too tired/dumb to make sense of your example and figure out how it relates to closures, but I can tell that it is far bigger and more complex than it needs to be for what you say you want.  You do not need to be using closures for this task, apart from the ones created by jQuery's functions. Also, re:

> It only updates the grid's colors on the last iteration

since you didn't use any timing functions, there is no reason for you to be seeing more than one update.

Here is a very simple demo of what you've described: http://jsbin.com/unuvuq/2/edit. Note the use of `setTimeout` - that or `setInterval` is what you need if you'd like to see each update at different times.

Code from demo below.
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var colours = [
      "aquamarine",
      "crimson",
      "goldenrod",
      "forestgreen",
      "dodgerblue",
      "orange"];

  $('[id^="cell"]').each(function() {
      var cell = $(this),
          time = 500 * cell.index();
      setTimeout(function() {
          cell.css('background', colours[cell.index()]);
      }, time);
  });

});
```

markup:

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="cell1"></div>
    <div id="cell2"></div>
    <div id="cell3"></div>
    <div id="cell4"></div>
    <div id="cell5"></div>
    <div id="cell6"></div>
</div>
```

CSS: (all arbitrary values chosen only to allow you to see what's going on)

```
.container { width: 200px; }

div[id^="cell"] {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid #000;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: My updating of the colors works. I don't want the updated backgrounds to appear slowly or anything. I do want them to update each time I run through the loop though and currently it's only updating with the last after the loop has completed. The grid is 3x2 like you provided and I have all the RGB values for each instance of the full grid in an array called test (as seen here http://jsfiddle.net/rBLLc/2/). When I run it in firefox or chrome, I get the last state of the grid only. I don't see it updating everytime the outer loop completes an iteration. The boxes need to update quickly.

Comment: What do you mean by "quickly"?  The updates can happen faster or slower depending on what time you give to `setTimeout`. If you don't want to use any kind of timing function then the updates should all occur at the same time and be instantaneous...which is what you say you are getting. So, do you want a single instantaneous update, or not?

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that the boxes don't change until there is no more javascript running, then it's expected behavior. The page will not update visually until all of the javascript returns. You can use setTimeout to return control after each effective iteration. Never sleep (spin loop) in javascript, use a timed callback.

```
function runUpdate(update) {
    if (update.length > 0) {
        update[0]();
    }

    if(update.length > 1) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            runUpdate(update.slice(1));
        }, 0);
    }
}
```

Replace your for loop with `runUpdates(updates);`. You can use the setTimeout time parameter to change the rate at which the boxes change color.

Comment: This just slows down the last update. When I add this in and run it attached to the js fiddle in the link above, it simply slows down its update on the last box. With the "test" array i have it's about 270ish pieces of RGB data. It seems to suffer from the same problem as before which is exactly as you said, once the javascript is done running it then updates the boxes (one at a time).